# Stopping a Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following code and sometimes the "decode()" function doesn't stop depending on the file it is decoding. I just wanted to stop the decoding if it is taking a lot of time. I tried calling the interrupt() function but it seems like "decode()" function doesn't stop. 
May I know what is the proper way of stopping the decode() function?

```
Thread decodeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         decode();
     }
});
```

This thread does not loop. The function "decode()" just doesn't return.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't forcibly stop threads because it's dangerous. You set a flag that tells the thread in question to exit from it's thread loop under controlled circumstances.

Your thread loop looks something along these lines:

```
void run() {
  while (shouldContinue) {
    doThreadWorkUnit();
  }
}
```

And somewhere else you set the `shouldContinue volatile variable` and wait for the thread to finish:

```
...
thread.shouldContinue = false;
thread.join();
...
```

**EDIT:**  (This is by support of Sephy)

**Suggested Methods for Stopping a Thread.**

Now that the Thread's `stop()`, `suspend()` etc., methods **have been deprecated**, **the only way to safely terminate a thread is to have it exit its run() method, perhaps via an un-checked exception.** In Sun's article, [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) , there are some suggestions for how to stop a thread without using the unsafe deprecated methods.

The method suggested there is to use a `volatile stop flag` (blinker in the code below)

```
private volatile Thread blinker;
public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}
public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            thisThread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

The volatile keyword is used to ensure prompt communication between threads. “A field may be declared volatile, in which case a thread must reconcile its working copy of the field with the master copy every time it accesses the variable. Moreover, operations on the master copies of one or more volatile variables on behalf of a thread are performed by the main memory in exactly the order that the thread requested.”

Comment: Note that it is important to declare shouldContinue as volatile. Some good reading about thread stopping : http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I'm such a newbie with threads. May I know what is the initial value of blinker? Should i set the thread I created to be blinker?

Comment: although this does not answer my original question, it still helped me with understanding thread so I'll give this answer an up-vote! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into `AsyncTask` as this handles many conditions (such as making distinctions between the background and the UI thread). For example:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // The thread was interrupted
                return null;
            }
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return "some output";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // TODO
    }
};
```

You can execute the task using:

```
task.execute("some input");
```

And cancel the task using:

```
task.cancel(true);
```

Comment: It still doesn't exit the thread. It is not actually looping in the application side but on the decoder side.

Comment: It is not safe to simply kill a thread, and doing so isn't even supported in Android. You will have to check `isCancelled()` manually at various stages of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Incidentally, what you're doing in the edited part of the OP is similar to checking for a cancellation flag.

Comment: actually I'm just calling ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() and there seems to be a bug or limitation in the AVCDecoder that it doesn't check if the value of the vcl hrd parameters is still valid or not that is why it takes so much time to finish.

Comment: I've already found where in the AVCDecoder the problem is, so we might just fix it. thanks again for your help.

Comment: although this does not answer my original question, it still helped me with understanding thread so I'll give this answer an up-vote! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Especially the part "**What if a thread doesn't respond to Thread.interrupt?**" and "**What should I use instead of Thread.stop?**"